# How to get list of files in a folder using .NET libraries

Tags: list, .net

Hopefully this is an easy question, but I am having some trouble finding samples of how to get a list of files in a sub folder in a document library.

Here's what I have, but I keep getting a "Value does not fall within the expected range" error when it does the ExecuteQuery().

```
// https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/teams/site/DocLibrary/folder1
parentSiteURL = "https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/teams/site";
libraryName = "DocLibrary";
folderName = "folder1";

ClientContext context = SetupSPContext(parentSiteURL, SharePointCRMDocumentsLoginName, SharePointCRMDocumentsPwd);

Web rootweb = context.Web;
string url2 = "/" + libraryName + "/" + folderName;
FolderCollection folderCollection = rootweb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(url2).Folders;

// Don't just load the folder collection, but the property on each folder too
context.Load(folderCollection, fs => fs.Include(f => f.ListItemAllFields));

// Actually fetch the data
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to set the `FolderServerRelativeUrl` of the `CamlQuery`. Setting the Scope attribute to **Recursive** will return all items but not folders, setting it to **RecursiveAll** will bring back items plus folders.

Please try below code to get the documents from `folder1` inside the `DocLibrary`

```
public static void GetListItemsInFolder()
{
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/teams/site");
            List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("DocLibrary");
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'>
                                    <Query>
                                    </Query>
                                </View>";
            camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/DocLibrary/folder1";
            ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.Load(listItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            ListItem itemOfInterest = listItems[0];
            string creator = itemOfInterest.FieldValues["Created_x0020_By"].ToString();
            string title = itemOfInterest.FieldValues["Title"].ToString();
        }
```

**UPDATED**

You can use below function to get the files from a specific folder **using CSOM**

```
public List<file> ListFiles(string libraryName, string folderName)
{
    using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("your site url")
    {
        List<portalfile> fileList = new List<portalfile>();

        var domain = "domain";
        var username = "username";
        var password = "password";
        clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        ListCollection lists = web.Lists;

        var docLib = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
        clientContext.Load(docLib,
                           d => d.Title,
                           d => d.RootFolder.Name);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        String folderUrl = String.Format("/{0}/{1}", docLib.RootFolder.Name, folderName);

        var folders = docLib.RootFolder.Folders;
        clientContext.Load(folders, fldrs => fldrs.Include(fldr => fldr.ServerRelativeUrl));
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        var folder = folders.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ServerRelativeUrl.ToLower() == folderUrl.ToLower());
        if (folder != null)
        {
            var files = folder.Files;
            clientContext.Load(files, fls => fls.Include(fl=> fl.Name));
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        return files.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get the 1st method to work, but I did get the 2nd one to work with one small change.  I changed the FirstOrDefault query on the folders to var folder = folders.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ServerRelativeUrl.ToLower().EndsWith(folderUrl.ToLower()));  The folderURL was shorter than the serverRelativeURL, but the EndsWith caught it.